# Azure purview , issue on scanning the schema of the json and the delta table

Tags: azure-purview

In my storage account , there are two types of data .

1. jsons
2. Delta Table (databricks)

which storing the different folder .

In Purview , I register the resource for the storage account and scan these two folders .
however after the scan , I can only see the folder name , but not the schema of the json , or the delta table .

[![screen shot of the folder][1]][1]

thanks and please help
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rWaiS.png

Answer (score 0):

You didn't provide enough context for understanding the reason behind your issue.

But, please consider that the tab 'schema' is visible in the Purview UI only when a 'tabular_schema' or a 'json_schema' is created together with the related components (columns, json properties, etc.): e.g. in the case of tabular schema:
[image]

This feature seems to be not well documented unfortunately.

More info here: [Update a Purview Resource Set's Tabular Schema](https://datasmackdown.com/oss/pyapacheatlas/purview/update-tabular-schema.html)